picom dimming inactive windows removes corner-radius on i3wm
I'm trying to have nice, rounded windows on my i3wm with picom with this config:
shadow = false;

#################################
#   Transparency / Opacity      #
#################################


# Opacity of inactive windows. (0.1 - 1.0, defaults to 1.0)
# inactive-opacity = 1
inactive-opacity = 0.85;

# Opacity of window titlebars and borders. (0.1 - 1.0, disabled by default)
# frame-opacity = 1.0

# Let inactive opacity set by -i override the '_NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY' values of windows.
# inactive-opacity-override = true
inactive-opacity-override = false;

# Default opacity for active windows. (0.0 - 1.0, defaults to 1.0)
active-opacity = 0.98

# Dim inactive windows. (0.0 - 1.0, defaults to 0.0)
inactive-dim = 0.5


#################################
#           Corners             #
#################################

# Sets the radius of rounded window corners. When > 0, the compositor will
# round the corners of windows. Does not interact well with
# `transparent-clipping`.
corner-radius = 7
round-corners = 1
# Exclude conditions for rounded corners.
rounded-corners-exclude = [
  "window_type = 'dock'",
  "window_type = 'desktop'"
];

I have a problem with this. When a window is inactive and, thus, dimmed, it has square corners instead of round corners.

The left one is dimmed, and the right one is active.
I have no idea if this is a bug or a default behavior of the picom compositor. And I didn't found any settings related to the dimmed window's corner radius.

had the same issue found the fix here in your picom.conf change the values for
#################################
#       General Settings        #
#################################

backend = "glx"; #the backend is the important part
use-damage = true;

then log out and log back into i3 (this is not necessary but mine was kinda flickering so I had to)
